# Evaluate dynamic property in watch window

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging, roslyn

I'm writing some system tests for my API. Because I want to catch backwards compatibility issues, I'm not referencing the Contract Model, using dynamic instead.

In code, I can peek inside that dynamic object's properties; however, if I try and evaluate that same expression in a watch window, it fails with the following error:

> error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for
>   'productDefinitionId' and no extension method accepting a first
>   argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a directive
>   or an assembly reference?)

[image]

It's the same in quick watch/immediate window. I remember being able to do this, but I've recently upgraded to VS2015 and therefore using the new Roslyn compiler (although I'm still on C# 5.0) - could this be it? If so, why?

### Update:

```cs
public dynamic LastAddedOrEditedProduct { get; private set; }

private void SetProductResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
{
    var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    LastAddedOrEditedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(result);
}
```

where result is a JSON like

```
{
  "productDefinitionId": 222
}
```

Comment: Check this [overview](https://github.com/Microsoft/ConcordExtensibilitySamples/wiki/CLR-Expression-Evaluators) of Expression Evaluator. This is what heppen when you write expression in the watch\immidiate window.

Comment: Can you post the code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @AlekseyL. - I've updated the question

Comment: Can't reproduce with any combination of debug settings. What do you mean by "I'm still on C#5"?

Comment: @IvanStoev I'm still targeting .NET Framework 4.5.1

Comment: I see. That's a different thing, has nothing in common with C# version. Did you try deleting and adding again the variable to the Watch window? Also, are you using the updated version of VS2015 (mine is Update 1)?

Comment: As I said, I've even tried immediate window/quick watch. Update 2 here (Version 14.0.25123.00)

Comment: @AlexandruMarculescu the update doesn't help, it doesn't reproduce the problem.. Can you post the code of `_productAccessor.LastAddedOrEditedProduct`

Comment: @AlekseyL. - updated

Comment: It looks like productDefinitionId isn't used later in the function, so perhaps it was optimized away. Then, maybe lastAddedProduct was interpreted as object because no further casting was required (after removing productDefinitionId). What happens if you add `Console.WriteLine(productDefinitionId)` ?

Comment: @AlexandruMarculescu, still not reproducible - works as expected

Comment: @Tomer - that works fine, that's why I added that variable in the watch in the screenshot; the issue is present only when trying to evaluate the expression in the watch window

Comment: @AlexandruMarculescu - Not sure I understand. If you add a usage for `productDefinitionId`, what do you see in the watch window? Is `lastAddedProduct` still interpreted as an object?

Comment: Same problem exists in VS 2019 as well

Answer (score 0):

You must use `.Value` then continue with the next object.

```
lastAddedProduct.Value.productDefinitionId
```